# How to order tables, history of what was changed and what is going to be changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm working on a project and I really need some help.
I'm using asp.net.

Requirments: Gridview,sql database 2008,sql data source.

```
Table name : ancientsItems
Columns:

ID|NAME |Age |Code |Repair |Date|
1  Vase  20   B829  Yes/No  x/xx/xxx

I would like to do the following:

If I select in the repair column value : YES , then two columns will be aded with time/final time:

ID|NAME |Age |Code |Repair | Time | Final Time |Date|
1  Vase  20   B829  Yes      xx       xx        x/xx/xxx
```

1. If I choose Yes in the repair column and choose the time when I
   started to repair , I would like to make a separate table with Under
   repair and there, all the rows with Repair term YES will be added.
   And when I'll add the final time in that row from the first table , 
   in a separate table Repaired  , will be added the row with all the
   values , name,age,id,repair,time,final,date.

Currently I made 3 tables : ancientsItems,Under repair,Repaired but I don't know how can I do the rest. Please if you don't mind helping me , I really appreciate.

Thank you .
    Irina

Comment: Ofc I know but I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are unclear here. Please edit your question to include some more detail and we can probably help you.

Some questions I have: What exactly are you having trouble with? Manipulating the page so the data can be edited or the database structure itself?

What happens if an item is repaired twice or more?

What happens to the "Age" of the item when the current date changes by a year? what (if anything) updates it?

From my understanding of the situation, I'd create the database tables like this:

```
AncientItems:
Id, Code, Name, ItemCreationDate (ItemCreationdate being Now-Item Age).

AncientItemRepairs:
Id, AncientItemId, RepairDate, Any other repair-specific info.
```

This means that you don't store the repair info alongside the item at all - instead, a single item can be linked to many repair records through the AncientItemId.

In addition, since we're now storing the ItemCreationDate instead of the age, it doesn't need to be updated annually.

As to how to update the Gridview in your ASP.Net project, we need some more information:

- How are you accessing the database (Entity Framework/ADO/?) ?
- Do you have an existing data access layer to use?
- What code have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: 1.after both columns - repair time ( time when it started ) , and finalization time ( when I finished the repair ), this row will be added in the table Reparations finished . and the column called Repair will get the value NO . and so on. 2.I'm using sqldata source in the gridview to get the values into it . I thought about making something but I don't know how to do it , and..if I need to write it tell me , it's just something I thought , not the code but the ideas

Comment: 1.When column ( repair ) value is set to : YES , then the other 2 columns will appear , the first one called : Reparation started at , and the other , Reparation ended at : ! . When I write the value in the reparations started at , then the entire row will be added into another table called : Under repair ! , and when I add the finalization date value , then the row from the under repair will be deleted , and the row with all the information will go in another table called : reparation finished !

Comment: The data structure you're using doesn't make sense - either I've misunderstood or you need to re-think it. Your data should be [normalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (in short, each fact should only appear once and should be authoritative.) What happens if your Yes/No column gets out of sync? Please edit your question to add more info - it's far easier to read than comments.